# Solutions $X_{k}$ to the equation $\sum_{k=0}^N X_{k} (-2^k)^n = 1$

Tags: linear-algebra, summation, exponentiation, products

In the proof of the lemma in [this paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1964-015-04/S0002-9939-1964-0165392-8/S0002-9939-1964-0165392-8.pdf), the author makes the following claim: Fix integer $N$ and let $n \leq N$. Then the solutions $X_0,\ldots,X_N$ to the equations
$$\sum_{k=0}^N X_{k} (-2^k)^n = 1 \qquad (n = 0,...,N)$$

are given by
$$X_k := \prod_{j \in \{0,\ldots,N\} \backslash\{k\}}\frac{1+2^j}{2^j - 2^k}$$
for $k = 0,\ldots,N$.

Could I get some hints on how to show that this is true? The author claims that this follows from *Cramer's rule* and *Vandermonde's expansion*, but I'm not familiar with the statements he is referring to.

EDIT: I've made some progress: the problem above is equivalent to finding numbers $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ such that the following equation is satisfied:
$$ \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\ -2^0 & -2^1 & \cdots & -2^N \\ (-2^0)^2 & (-2^1)^2 & \cdots & (-2^N)^2  \\ \vdots & \vdots &\ddots& \vdots\\(-2^0)^N & (-2^1)^N & \cdots & (-2^N)^N \\  \end{pmatrix}}_{=: A}\begin{pmatrix} X_0 \\ X_1 \\ X_2 \\  \vdots \\  X_N\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\1 \\ 1 \\  \vdots \\  1\end{pmatrix} $$

The matrix $A$ is a square Vandermonde matrix, and so
$$\det(A) = \prod_{0 \leq i < j \leq N} (2^i - 2^j).$$
Thus, $A$ is invertible. Cramer's rule tells us that for $k = 0,\ldots, N$,
$$X_k = \frac{\det(A_k)}{ \det(A)},$$
where $A_k$ is the matrix $A$ with the (zero-based)  $k$th column replaced with $(1\; 1 \; \cdots \; 1)^\top$.

However, I'm not sure how to calculate $\det(A_k)$ and simplify the expression for $X_k$. Could I get some suggestions on how to finish the computation?

Comment: Both terms are referring to matrices. So try to figure out matrix wich has coefficients given such $X_i$ and powers of two.

Comment: @AdamWrzesiński I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @Joseph Kwong: $n$ is not fixed. $(X_0,\dots,X_N)$ is the solution of the system of $N+1$ linear equations indexed by $n$. Now, ask your friend Google for "Cramer's rule", and "Vandermonde"

Comment: @AnneBauval I've made an update with your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general [Vandermonde determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix)
$$V(x_0, x_1,\dots,x_N):=
\begin{vmatrix}
1&1&1&\dots &1\\
x_0&x_1& x_2&\dots&x_N\\
x_0^2&x_1^2&x_2^2&\dots&x_N^2\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
x_0^N& x_1^N& x_2^N&\dots & x_N^N
\end{vmatrix}$$
is well-known to be given by
$$V(x_0,x_1,\dots,x_N)=\prod_{1\le i<j\le N}(x_j-x_i).$$
By Cramer's formula,
$$X_k=\frac{\det A_k}{\det A},$$
where
$$\det A=V(-2^0, -2^1,\dots,-2^N)=\prod_{1\le i<j\le N}(2^i-2^j)$$
and
$$\det A_k=V(-2^0,\dots,-2^{k-1},1, -2^{k+1},\dots,-2^N)\\=\prod_{1\le i<j\le N\atop i,j\ne k}(2^i-2^j)\prod_{1\le i<k}(2^i+1)\prod_{k<j\le N}(-1-2^j).$$
Therefore,
$$X_k=\prod_{1\le i<k}\frac{2^i+1}{2^i-2^k}\prod_{k<j\le N}\frac{-1-2^j}{2^k-2^j}= \prod_{j\in\{0,\dots,N\} \backslash\{k\}}\frac{1+2^j}{2^j-2^k}.$$

Comment: Ah I see. The step I was missing is that $A_k$ is also a Vandermonde matrix with $x_k = 1$. Thanks for your help!